# Showing textbox by button - Jquery rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have jquery here:

```
  $(".cellphone-add").on "click", (e) ->
    if $(".cellphone2").show == true
      $(".cellphone3").removeClass('hidden')
      return false
    if $(".cellphone3").show == true
      $(".cellphone4").removeClass('hidden')
      return false
    if $(".cellphone4").show == true
      $(".cellphone5").removeClass('hidden')
      return false
    $(".cellphone2").removeClass('hidden')
    return false
    e.preventDefault()
    return false
```

And this is my view:

```
    .row
      .pull-right.container
        .btn.btn-success.btn-xs.cellphone-add
          Add another field?
    .cellphone2.input-group.hidden
      = f.text_field :cellphone_2, class: 'char-max-length form-control', :maxlength => 11, :id => "cellphone-value-2"
      %span.input-group-btn
        .actions
          %a#cr2.btn.cellphone-remove.btn-xs.btn-link{:href => "#"}
            %i.icon-remove
    .cellphone3.input-group.hidden
      = f.text_field :cellphone_3, class: 'char-max-length form-control', :maxlength => 11, :id => "cellphone-value-3"
      %span.input-group-btn
        .actions
          %a#cr3.btn.cellphone-remove.btn-xs.btn-link{:href => "#"}
            %i.icon-remove
    .cellphone4.input-group.hidden
      = f.text_field :cellphone_4, class: 'char-max-length form-control', :maxlength => 11, :id => "cellphone-value-4"
      %span.input-group-btn
        .actions
          %a#cr4.btn.cellphone-remove.btn-xs.btn-link{:href => "#"}
            %i.icon-remove
    .cellphone5.input-group.hidden
      = f.text_field :cellphone_5, class: 'char-max-length form-control', :maxlength => 11, :id => "cellphone-value-5"
      %span.input-group-btn
        .actions
          %a#cr5.btn.cellphone-remove.btn-xs.btn-link{:href => "#"}
            %i.icon-remove
```

What I'm going to do is I want to show my textbox one by one.

For example, I click once the button "Add Another field?" and the `cellphone_2` div will show. Then I click it again and 2nd textbox will show. Just like that. My code on view is okay but I know that there's something wrong on my jquery.

Thanks! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the first hidden element and show it on each click while removing the hidden class:

```
$(".cellphone-add").on "click", (e) ->
  $(".input-group.hidden").first().show().removeClass "hidden"
```